# Odd difference between script and interpreter: can't reference class attribute as default argument in __init__ function

Tags: python, class

```
class f:
    x = 5
    def __init__(self, bar = f.x):
        self.bar = bar

    def fn(r, test = print(f.x)):
        return r
```

I ran the code above in python interpreter (IDLE) and it worked perfectly fine. Then, I pasted the code in atom and ran the code in interactive mode and it returned the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 28, in <module>
    class f:
  File "testing.py", line 30, in f
    def __init__(self, bar = f.x):
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

Why the difference? And why is "f" not defined? I thought that when python hits the class statement is creates a class object, and **then** proceeds to create the function objects inside the class body.

Comment: `bar = f.x` is the issue. You are trying to define the default of the argument `bar` to be the attribute `x` of `f`. As `f` is not defined (or is currently being defined) it is an error to reference it

Comment: That almost certainly didn't actually work in IDLE. You probably ran something subtly different and *thought* you ran the same thing as you posted, perhaps because IDLE handles multiline statements weird.

Comment: Also, the class object is created *after* the functions, and it doesn't get assigned to a variable until the very last step of executing a class statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default values for function parameters are calculated at the time the function is being defined. But you can't reference a class until *after* the class definition is completed.

When you were doing it in IDLE, I suspect you had a previous definition of `f` and you were redefining it. Until the new definition is completed, the old definition was still in effect, so `f.x` referenced the old value of `f.x`.

When you put it in a script, it was starting fresh, so there was no previous definition of `f`, and it got an error trying to evaluate `f.x` during the function definition.

As a simpler example, consider a statement like

```
x = x + 1
```

If you put this in a script by itself, you'll get an error. But if you use it in IDLE, and you had earlier done

```
x = 3
```

in the same IDLE session, it would work.

Comment: Yep you were exactly right - I restarted IDLE and pasted the same code in and it didn't work. Guess I had already defined f when I first tried this code out. Thanks for the help!